# Node.js - Cannot find module 'websocket'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and I need to use a module `websocket`. My server:

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

$ node --version
v6.11.5

$ npm --version
3.10.10
```

Installed a module with `$ npm install websocket`, but when I tried my file it gives me this:

```
$ node /var/www/js/test.js
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'websocket'
```

This is the first line of my JS file:

```
var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;
```

I also tried the following commands:

```
$ npm install websocket (with and without -g flag)
$ npm link websocket
$ npm install -d
```

But nothing helped.

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "websocket": "^1.0.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: is there anything in package,json file

Comment: update node version

Comment: @rahulmr updated question, will try to update node

Comment: websocket documentation says its checked with node 6.2.0

Comment: @rahulmr thanks, updated node to `v8.8.1` fixed it.

Comment: is it working??

Comment: yes it is, I don't know why I haven't tried it before

Answer (score 1):

you have to try this `var websocket = require('websocket');` in your file

Comment: Updating node to the latest version helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo npm install websocket`
Then import to file using `var WebSocketClient = require('websocket').client;`
Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add in test.js, assuming it's at the root of your node directory:

`process.chdir(__dirname);`

Or:

`cd /var/www/js/ && node test.js`.

The working directory needs to be the one where `node_modules` and `package.json` are.

To print the working directory for the node application:

`console.log(process.cwd());`

Comment: Thanks, but I already managed it to work with updating node to `v8.8.1`